# adding a button in the edit menu of a webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to add a link or button in the menu that appears when you click on the top left corner of a web part in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is use JQuery to look for all the Verb menus present in the page, then add a new DOM elemente to that menu tag.

I deployed this custom javascript code to all the pages using a delegate control with the id AdditionalPageHead. This delegate control added the custom script and a link to JQuery script file. JQuery was also bundled in the solution package.

Answer (score 2):

These menu items are usually called "Verbs", there is a decent tutorial here on adding them.

http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/customizing-custom-web-part-menu-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I want to add a verb in all the webparts of a page when I activate a feature I created. I'm able to do it in 2007 by linking my feature action to an assembly. It seems not posssible in 2010. Since I need a Javascript action, I might just need a way to inject javascript in a page, then this javascript will do the rest.